# C++ c-tor handle default member value construction exception?

Tags: c++, exception, initialization, member, iso

I want to handle exception in a default-value constructed class member. Something like this:

```
int func()
{
    throw 9.0;

    return 9;
}

struct T
{
    T() try {
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout << __func__ << endl;
    }
    int a{func()};
} ;
```

Is it possible? And what does the latest ISO C++ standard says about it?

EDIT: I actually verified myself it works on most compilers but is it well-defined and should I normally use this construct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that exception is rethrown if you catch it.

Comment: Why so? Can you explain?

Comment: Ah, *The currently handled exception is rethrown if control reaches the end of a handler of the function-try-block
of a constructor or destructor.*

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/2EDkHo). Note that exceptions handled by a constructor's function-try-block are rethrown (which is usually what you want if construction failed).

Comment: OK but is this behavior which is well-defined - can I expect it to work everywhere?

Comment: Also if I nest the 'try-catch' statement into function body then the exception isn't being catch (at least in Clang).

Comment: @FISOCPP: Yes, that's true; I shouldn't have mentioned that, sorry. A function-level block will catch exceptions from sub-objects, then rethrow, which is what you want because the complete object can't be initialised if a sub-object failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Yes, that exception would be handled by the function-level handler just like any other thrown by a member's initialiser. Note that, in the function-try-block of a constructor, the exception is rethrown after handling it. This is what you want if the initialisation of a sub-object failed, since the complete object is not valid.

> And what does the latest ISO C++ standard says about it?

I don't have C++14 yet, but C++11 said:

> 15/4: An exception thrown during the execution of the compound-statement or, **for constructors** and destructors,
>   **during the initialization** or destruction, respectively, **of the class’s subobjects**, transfers control to a handler
>   in a function-try-block in the same way as an exception thrown during the execution of a try-block transfers
>   control to other handlers.

and 15.3/15 specifies that it's rethrown in this case.

> should I normally use this construct?

Probably not - there's little you can do to handle the failure of a sub-object's initialisation, so usually no point in catching and rethrowing the exception. You might want to report the error as the exception passes through.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, you can only catch the exception for thing you do inside the constructor body, like this:

```
struct T
{
    T() {
    try { a = func();}
    catch(...) 
    {
        cout << __func__ << endl;
    }
    }
}
```

Also you should catch the exception, but not in the ctor, but where the object is constructed. That is:

```
try {
    T t;//construct
}
catch(...)
{};
```

That way you get the failure on construction.

Comment: The syntax in the question is quite valid if that's what you mean.